# Selection/Filter with indices using pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a 3-dimensional numpy array, for example:

```
 x = [[[0.3, 0.2, 0.5],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.7],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]]]
```

The indices array is also 3-dimensional, like:

```
indices = [[[0],
            [1],
            [2]]]
```

I expect the output is:

```
 output= [[[0.3],
           [0.2],
           [0.6]]]
```

I tried the torch.index_select and torch.gather function, but I couldn't find a right way to deal with the dimension. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `x.gather(dim=2, indices)`? That works for me.

Comment: yes, it works!!! Thank you! I must I lost my mind after trying too much!

Comment: @beepretty No worries! Happens with most of us :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Please let me know if there is any better solution.

```
torch.cat([torch.index_select(a.view(1, -1), 1, i.view(1, -1)[0]) 
                                         for a, i in zip(x, indices)])
```